# How to select some specific columns in a Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

In `Matlab`, if i want select some specified col of a `Mat` and **at the same time** copy them to another `Mat`, i write a code like this:

```
mm = nn(:,[1 3]);
```

how to do like this in OpenCV?

Comment: Reading the documentation of the [OpenCV `Mat` class](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) would seem like a good first step. Shouldn't take too long to find a method that gives you a subset of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no OpenCV function to do this in the general case.

---

If the selected columns are contiguous, you can use the `Mat` constructor that accepts two `Range`:

```
Mat mm = nn(Range::all(), Range(1, 4)).clone(); // range end is exclusive
```

and `mm` will contain the columns 1,2,3 of `nn`.

---

In the general case, you should copy each column in the correct place. There's no way of doing this actually *"at the same time"*, but outside of the function `selectColumns` you get the *"at the same time"* behavior.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void selectColumns(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, const vector<int>& columns)
{
    assert(!columns.empty());

    // Be sure that the column indices are valid.
    // They may not be sorted.
    auto limits = minmax_element(columns.begin(), columns.end());
    assert(*limits.first >= 0);
    assert(*limits.second < src.cols);

    int cols = int(columns.size());
    dst.create(src.rows, cols, src.type());
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)  {
        src.col(columns[i]).copyTo(dst.col(i));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat3f nn(3, 5);
    randu(nn, Scalar(0), Scalar(255,255,255));

    Mat mm;
    selectColumns(nn, mm, { 0,2 });

    return 0;
}
```

---

Remember that in C++ indices are 0-based, while in Matlab indices are 1-based.